# How To Toggle All Checboxes With JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table whose values are generated dynamically with PHP.  Each row in the table has a checkbox.  In the table is a header column, that has a "Accept All" button.

When a user clicks the "Accept All" button, all select boxes are checked.  However, I want to add a toggle-like functionality:  if no boxes are checked, then pressing the button selects all; if all boxes are checked, then pressing the button would unselect all.

Here's my JQuery code for select all:

```
//Approves all
$('#approve_all_questions').click(function () {
    $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
});
```

I'm having trouble getting it to toggle correctly.  I've tried this:

```
//Toggle
$('#approve_all_questions').click(function () {

    if($("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true))
    {
        $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
    }
  });
```

But that doesn't work.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true)` sets the `checked` attribute to `true` and returns a jQuery object which *always* evaluates to `true`.

Maybe you want

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', function(i, val) {
    return !val;
});
```

which inverts the `checked` value for each checkbox.

If you want to select or deselect all at once, you could do:

```
var $boxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    $unselected = $boxes.not(function(){ 
        return this.checked;
    });

// if there are any unselected boxes, it selects all, else it deselects all
$boxes.prop('checked', $unselected.length > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/6mK9q/1/

just one parameter needed, second one sets checked to true and returns object (which is considered as true)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another slab of code for you with a working demo: http://jsbin.com/agomuc/edit.
Please notice the use of `.live()`, if you want to use `.click()` you'll have to put your handler into

`$(document).ready(function(){

    // handler here

});`

Answer (score 0):

i prefer my solution:

```
$(".selectAllCheckBox").live("click", function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked')){
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

;)